# Regular Expression to include from word to semicolon in python

Tags: python, regex

So I have a string as follows:

```
...
data={{...{...}...{..}}};
...
```

I want to retrieve everything from "data=" to the final ";"

Also, there are no spaces or semicolons inside the data

Edit :

"Real Data" : `data={"info":{"foo":"bar","blah":"boo"};`

Output : `'{"info":{"foo":"bar","blah":"boo"}'`

Doing this in a python script using `re`, once extracted ill serialize it into JSON

Comment: Please show some real data, and what your expected output will be. Is this in an editor, select statement or a program variable?  What OS, program, RDBMS or language?  Not all regex engines are created equal.

Comment: @Gary_W see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `(?<=data=).*?(?=;)`:

- `(?<=data=)` lookbehind: it will anchor right after **data=** string
- `(?=;)` lookahead: it will anchor right before **;** string
- `.*?`: it will match all chars between anchors

```js
const string = 'data={"info":{"foo":"bar","blah":"boo"};';
const regex = /(?<=data=).*?(?=;)/mg;

console.log(string.match(regex)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing fancy needed; you can simply use `/data=\S+;/`

This captures `data=`, then any non-whitespace character(s), then `;`.

```js
const string = '[OMITTED] data={{...{...}...{..}}}; [OMITTED]';
const regex = /data=\S+;/

console.log(string.match(regex)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is strict to find the object so that char `{` must be after `data=` having anything between, including the `newline`, and it allows spaces after `=` and `}`

```
(?:data=)(\s*{(?:.|\n)*})(?:\s*;)
```

It's good to have it strict because there could be some other variable named `data`

https://regex101.com/r/0WVKcE/2